# how to insert $$ and put the cursor between them in autopair-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I often use AuCTeX to make my latex documents so i use the dollar `$` sign a lot.

If [autopair](http://code.google.com/p/autopair/) minor mode is enabled, when you insert a `(` it automatically inserts a `)` (there are some exceptions where it doesn't, for example, if you insert it after a `\`, but i like the exceptions) and put the cursor between them, so you have `(<cursor>)`, now if you type <kbd>a+b)</kbd>, you get `(a+b)` and not `(a+b))`.

I would like to have a similar behaviour with `$` that works only in `TeX-mode` when i enable `autopair-mode`.

I've tried adding the followint to my .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
       #'(lambda ()
             (push '(?$ . ?$)
                    (getf autopair-extra-pairs :everywhere))))
```

but it does not work for some reason.

The problem is that you usually have a lot of expression `$...$` and when you insert a single `$`, all the text before that `$` gets a wrong coloration which is annoying and then after you close the initial `$` the text after the initial `$` gets fixed.

Comment: Is `TeX-mode-hook` definitely correct? It seems to be an all lower-case `tex-mode-hook` in Emacs 24.

Comment: @phils i think it's correct because i have other `TeX-mode-hook` that work properly

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about AuCTeX, but this works for `latex-mode`

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex-mode" '(modify-syntax-entry ?$ "\"" latex-mode-syntax-table))
```

Not sure what the right syntax-table is for AuCTeX.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I have code on Github for autopairing dollar signs and \[\] in Latex.

https://github.com/tomathan/autopair-latex/blob/master/autopair-latex.el

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is essentially the same as event_jr's (i tried it but it didn't work for me). The main point is change the syntax entry of $ so it is traited as " (strings). Check the very end of http://code.google.com/p/autopair/issues/detail?can=1&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=18